# error in building workspace in Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, spring, jsp, web

I am using Eclipse Helios for my web apps development,whenever i started my eclipse Helios it shows the following error

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'MyProject'.
The builder launch configuration could not be found.
The builder launch configuration could not be found.
```

The project i load in the workspace is MyProject i have googled for the error but i don't get a working solution please Help me

Thanks in Advance
Umesh Annegirikar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried the following solution ?

```
1.Select the right project
2.Choose "project"on the tool bar -> Properties
3.Click "Builders" in the menus of the popped up window
4.Remove the missing builders
```

[Reference link](http://jibeex.blogspot.in/2011/05/eclipse-error-builder-launch.html)